# Calling function via pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, recursion

Here is a simple code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
void (*func[2])(int);
void main(int n=1)
{
    int i;
    cout<<endl<<n;
    func[0]=&exit;
    func[1]=&main;
    i=++n<=10;
    (func[i])(n);
}
```

Here I am satisfied with the output (i.e. 1 to 10 in different lines).  The only thing which confused me was that why the global pointer is of the type void (*ptr[2])(int). If possible, please explain in simple words that why this pointer was taken so specifically

Comment: Reading about [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might help you decode it.

Comment: Also, you should know that technically your program have *undefined behavior*. The C++ specification says that `main` must be defined to return an `int`, and take either no arguments or two arguments (an `int` and an array of `char` pointers).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : this is a simple code for some riddle so it does not conform to standard c++ programming rules. I got my answer in first comment. Thanks alot eveyone for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a pointer, it's an array of two pointers.

This is a function:

```
void func(int);
```

This is a pointer to a function:

```
void (*func)(int);
```

and this is an array of two pointers to functions:

```
void (*func[2])(int);
```

So `func[i]` points to `exit` if `i` is zero (i.e. if `n` is greater than 10), and points to `main` otherwise, where `i` is 1.

Note that you're not allowed to call `main` recursively like this, nor to give `main` any signature other than `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`. (At least, that's the case in modern C++; these rules presumably don't apply to the prehistoric dialect your compiler accepts).